# Calling WebClient.DownloadFile doesn't download when calling application Windows task scheduler but downloads when run manually?

Tags: c#, windows, task

I have a C# application that uses WebClient.DownloadFile to download a file.
The url passed is a .ashx page that takes in parameters for email and password.
Example:
address is like this: https://www.asdf.com/API/catalog.ashx?email={EMAILADDRESS}&pass={PASSWORD}

```
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadFile(address, "Test.xml");
            }
```

When I run the .exe manually, it downloads the file correctly.
I've also run the .exe through a batch file manually which outputs logs messages to a file and that downloads correctly as well.
When I use a windows task to run either the .exe or the batch file, the log files show me that the download times out.

I've used all manner of options, like running as highest privileges, running as administrator, the windows version, none of them have worked for me.

Anyone have an idea on how to get the file download working with the task scheduler?

Comment: `the log files show me that the download times out` Please include those log file entries in your post.

Comment: Does it work if you change `Test.xml` to a fully qualified filename in a folder that has full access for `Everyone`?